# Не работает datalist в HTML

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт на хостинге. И есть там input с вариантом выбора из datalist тега.

[image: Вот такой]

Все прекрасно работало. Я всегда сайт периодически проверяю на работоспособность. И в какой-то момент заметил, что при нажатии на стрелку не открываются варианты для заполнения. Просто тыкаешь и не открывается. Посмотрел через F12 - datalist заполнен. В консоли ошибок нет. Сначала грешил на JS, но все работает идеально. На моб. устройствах работает, на большинстве браузеров - тоже. Но в Microsoft Edge - нет, хотя до этого все прекрасно работало. Код никто не трогал, гарантия 100%. CSS тоже отлично работает и работал до этого момента в Edge.

В чем может быть проблема? Грешу на причуды Microsoft Edge.

UPD: Нашел проблему, но не знаю, как пофиксить. В MS Edge, если в даталисте тегов options больше 20, то даталист просто не отображается. Это вообще реально пофиксить или это приколы Edge?

Comment: какая версия edge? кэш браузера почистите

Comment: Edge Самый новый, кеш, разумеется, чистил)

Comment: а при двойном клике на поле список появляется?